# Android App keeps logged out

Tags: android, gps, alarmmanager

I have an Android App which has a function for users to log in. The problem is that the app keeps shuttting down. The intervals are irregular. Sometimes it last 3 minutes and sometimes 10 minutes.

A backdrop:
When the user logs in, the app sends the coordinates to our server. The coordinates are fetched from GPS.

At fixed intervals. We have added AlarmManager so that the app continues to function when the phone goes into the sleeping mode.

It does not help either.

What we've noticed:
If we were to get coordinates from cell towers, the battery life is much long and we have tested once and it was able to hold the session for 10 hours. However the coordinates provided were not accurate hence we can't use this method.

We've seen someone writing about sticky we are not quite sure how that works.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi I would probably post the code when it gets more critical.

Answer (score 0):

aGPS, or Assisted GPS, is not going to give you a very accurate location.  You're estimating your position using 1..n cell towers.  How it works ... [image]

"Using cell tower triangulation (3 towers), it is possible to determine a phone location to within an area of 'about' 3/4 square mile." --their quote not mine.  Hate on them not this post.  I'm trying to be helpful ;)  http://wrongfulconvictionsblog.org/2012/06/01/cell-tower-triangulation-how-it-works/

You probably need a background service running if you're trying to periodically get and record the user's position.

Comment: Hi Bill thank you for the information on GPS. At the current moment the more critical issue is that the app keeps logging out. I am not sure whether that is due to the internet connection, i.e. because the app posts data to the server or that the mobile phone is out of resources. I've turned out the developer options on my mobile phone we shall see what the results are.